# Replace between curly brackets and treat what is inside as variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following issue.
I need to display the following according to the environment set by the user (currency) :

```
$sMyPromotion = 'this offer starts at {5000}';

// 5000 is the value in my default currency (euros for example) and
// needs to be converted to the user currency
// so I have a function that converts : convertRate($Price, $aCurrency) 
//  that returns for example: 6000 USD.
```

But I'm stuck on how to take what is between curly brackets and the brackets and replace it by what is returned by convertRate as I'm not comfortable with regexp, preg...

I need something that does:

```
$sOccurency = what is between curly brackets and the brackets;

$sMyPromotion = Replace $sOccurency  with convertRate($sOccurency, $aCurrency);
```

So in this example:
    $sMyPromotion = 'this offer starts at {5000}';

Expected result:
    $sMyPromotion = 'this offer starts at 6000 $';

Comment: Are the curly brackets always balanced? Can they be nested also?

Comment: OP, please do not place tags in your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sMyPromotion = preg_replace('@{(\d+)}@', '\\1$', $sMyPromotion);
```

or use preg_replace_callback:

```
$sMyPromotion = preg_replace_callback ( '@{(\d+)}@', 
        function ($matches)
        {

            return $matches [1] . '$';

        }, $sMyPromotion );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the variable into the string? Like `$sMyPromotion = 'this offer starts at '.$valueYouNeed;`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a little bit more complicated than I guess you realize. Most obvious is that you'll have to deal with exchange rates for all currencies you want to handle.

```
function TranslateRate($str, $currency)
{
    $def_rate = 100;

    if (!preg_match('/\{(\d+)\}/', $str, $value))
        return $str; // Noting to translate

    if ($currency = '$')
    {
        $dollar_rate=120;

        $val_rate = ($value[1] / $def_rate);

        return preg_replace('/(\{\d+\})/', $val_rate*$dollar_rate, $str);
    }

    // 'Unknown currency';

    return $str;
}

echo TranslateRate("this offer starts at {5000}", '$');
```

This is a very crude version of your translation routine, but it should give you the idea on how to continue.

I don't even know how to use floating point arithmetic's in php so the rates are in cents.

See it working [at phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d22-rkt).